# If click any file in the group window, the program turns off

Tags: iar

if i click c file, program is stop working. program is just turn off... no error mesaage

I looked for a solution to the problem on the iar homepage, but there was no problem I had.

add other file, but same..

I don't know what to do because it just bounces off without any messages
I'm using Windows 11 and the iar version is 9.40.1
I used it normally when it was Windows 10, upgraded to 11 and reinstalled it, and this happened

Comment: It sounds like you triggered a bug in the IDE. My suggestion is that you contact Iar support.